# Capybara doesn't close browser when Net::ReadTimeout error happens

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am running tests for a Rails app with Capybara, Cucumber and Selenium Webdriver (Ruby). I have a question: why Capybara doesn't close browser when Net::ReadTimeout happens even I had a hook which asked browser to quit after each test scenario? How can I force it to close the browser when Net::ReadTimeout occurs? 
This is my hooks.rb

```rb
after do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    page.driver.browser.save_screenshot("#{scenario.__id__}.png")
  end
  Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
  Capybara.current_session.driver.quit
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another solution that works for me.

1. add gem `capybara-screenshot`
2. configure your `spec_helper.rb` in such way:

```
Capybara::Screenshot.autosave_on_failure = true

Capybara::Screenshot.prune_strategy = :keep_last_run 

Capybara.default_wait_time = 60
```

Comment: also you can save all failed scenarios screenshots and name it as you want

Comment: Thanks but I can save failed screenshots. But in this case, when Net::ReadTimeout happen, the scenario failed without closing browser. That's the problem.

Comment: James, that's why I offer you use Capybara.screenshot gem. I had the same problem as you before and opted for gem.

Comment: Thank @Tatyana Kosachova